# Newbie: In Jersey framework, how to get HTML form object data in my case?

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, jersey

When client side submit a **HTML form**, it will send a form object to server, like:

```
params={username: USER_INPUT_USERNAME,
       passworkd: USER_INPUT_PASSWORD}
```

Then, client ajax send the **params** object to my **Jersey** server.

On the server side, how can I get and parse this HTML form object data `params`:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public FormResult getFormResult(@QueryParam("params") Object params) {
                 //How can I define the type of the "params" I received?
                 //Do I need to create a Java Bean which represent the HTML form, 
                 //and use the bean as the type of paprams? or any other way?
}
```

(In above code, the return type `FormResult` is an POJO bean which describe the result to response to client)

When I receive the `params` HTML form object data, how can I define the **type** of the `params` ?(above I defined it with type "`Object`", which is wrong).

Do I must define a **POJO bean** to represent the HTML form and use that bean to describe the type of the `params`?? or any other way in Jersey?

(If create POJO bean for the HTML form, If there are **check boxes** on the **HTML form**, the `params` will be an dynamic object, only checked field will be added to the params object, which is also a problem)

Anybody can help?

Comment: You can make your life a lot easier if you make the client-side code send valid JSON data. You're already most of the way there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@QueryParam` maps an individual queryString parameter, so for a GET request you need to enumerate all your parameters as method arguments:

```
@GET
getFormResult(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("age") int age, ... )
```

---

If the `params` that you mentioned is actually one query string parameter (`http://your.rest.service?params=somethingHere`), you can map that to some class that has a constructor taking a `String`, or a static `valueOf(String)` method where you do the actual parsing.

```
@GET
getFormResult(@QueryParam("params") FormData formData);
```

And the FormData class can look like this:

```
public class FormData {
    public FormData(String s) {
        // populate fields based on the content of s
    }

    // getters / setters / whatever ...
}
```

---

EDIT:
For checkboxes, it's not as dynamic as it looks: they have the same name, so you'll have one-, several- or no- value(s) associated with that name, depending on what the user checked. Therefore, a `@QueryParam("chk") String[] checkedValues` should be enough to handle the "dynamic" aspects here (actually, 'multi-valued' would be a better word).